# What is the difference between log-likelihood and expected pointwise log predictive density

Tags: bayesian, maximum-likelihood

I'm currently switching from Maximum Likelihood Estimations to Bayesian inference models where I can specify my own priors.

I used to do K-fold cross-validation: estimate the parameters on the training set, and compute the log-likelihood on the testing set.

Is this what is called the expected log predictive density? It seems like it would be, but I have a small doubt...

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**"expected log predictive density"** is the expected density on **the rest of the samples in the population outside of your training and validation set**, which is impossible to calculate.

But it can be proved that **"average log likelihood on the validation sets of the cross-validation" is proportional to "expected log predictive density"**.

That is why in pratice people try to maximize the "expected log predictive density" by maximizing the "average log likelihood on the validation sets of the cross-validation".

Another thing is, since you are already using **Bayesian method**, why bother using cross-validation? A better option is to pick the model that can maximize the **marginal likelihood**, or minimize **BIC** if you can't calculate marginal likelihood directly.